# Is there still mystery about spin crisis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, relativity

The gluon is a vector boson; like the photon, it has a spin of 1. If this is true and if we know the spin of protons and neutrons then why the news  [SPIN COMES FROM GLUONS?](http://www.physics4all.com/spin-comes-from-gluons/)
 is telling that,  we aren't quite sure about overall nuclear spin?

Comment: Do you understand the addition of angular momentum in quantum mechanics? Without that the answers to the question will need to be taken on faith.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that we are quite sure what the overall nuclear spin is; we are not sure how to obtain it mathematically from available models.

Due to the phenomenon of [color confinement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement), there are no gluons at low energies in QCD (the theory underlying nuclear physics). Importantly, you can't say there are this or that many gluons in any proton or neutron. Thus you can't simply add or subtract the spin of a few gluons to those of quarks, and expect to get the spin of proton. To obtain the spin of proton (as a low-energy bound-state of quarks) is a hard (non-perturbative) problem in QCD whose analytic solution does not seem to be within theoretical reach at the moment.

However, the problem simplifies if you consider a toy model of QCD: QCD at large number of colors (the standard QCD has only three colors). Since at large number of colors [the mathematical problem simplifies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/N_expansion), this model is more tractable analytically, than the standard QCD with only three colors. In this toy model, there are candidate states for baryons ("protons" and "neutrons"), that are called [Skyrmions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyrmion), whose properties, including their spin, matches expectation.